# How to create temporary welcome page after registration?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using User plugin in october cms. I have allowed user registration only after user activation.
But, when users register on signup page,a flash message appears that- an activation mail has been send. But user remains on the signup page.
Is there a way to direct user to a temporary welcome page, after the registration and allow only to home page after the activation.

Comment: hmm can you use "Redirect to" property of account component to redirect after successful registration, you can put `temp welcome page` there so user redirect there.

Comment: But redirect won't  work till the user doesn't activate(confirm) the account. As the "user plugin" doesn't even allow user to login without confirming their account.